# Adding reference points and lines to a geom_line() plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame like `dat1:

```r
dat1 <- data.frame(idx = 1:200,
                   fit = rnorm(200,10,0.5))
cis <- data.frame(uci=dat1$fit+0.5,
                  lci = dat1$fit-0.5)
dat1 <- cbind(dat1,cis)
```

I also have 3 other objects where I have stored "points of interest" (or `poi1:3`) for dat1.

```r
poi1 <- c(30,59,120,150)
poi2 <- c(10,42,110,165,190)
poi3 <- c(50, 100)
```

I made a line plot with confidence bands for `dat1` using this code:

```r
p<-
ggplot(dat1, aes(x=idx, y=fit))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lci, ymax = uci), alpha = 0.3)+
  labs(x="Distance", y="Var1")
p
```

[image]

I want to highlight the "points of interest" along this line. I want to highlight the points for `poi1` red, the points for `poi2` blue, and the points for `poi3` green. I can use `geom_vline()` to make them all vertical:

```r
p+
  geom_vline(xintercept =poi1, color="red")+
  geom_vline(xintercept = poi2, color = "blue")+
  geom_vline(xintercept = poi3, color = "green")
```

But I would actually like the points for `poi1` and `poi2` to be either blue and red points (instead of lines, and leaving `poi3` as a vertical green line), or much "shorter" versions of what is done by `geom_vline` (both above and below the black line). I cannot get `geom_point()` to behave correctly and do this. Do I need to format it differently, or how can I accomplish this? 
Also, how can I next add a legend in the top corner that denotes which line/point and color denotes which group of `poi`? For instance if they are points (plus the green line) it will have a red point and say "poi1"  a blue point next to the word "poi2" and a small green line next to the work "poi3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the most straightforward way to add the colored points is to have separate calls to `geom_point` and supply `poi1`, `poi2`, and `poi3` as the method to subset your plot.

So, the code would look something like this:

```
p +
  geom_point(data=dat1[which(dat1$idx %in% poi1),], color='red', size=3) +
  geom_point(data=dat1[which(dat1$idx %in% poi2),], color='blue', size=3) +
  geom_point(data=dat1[which(dat1$idx %in% poi3),], color='green', size=3)
```

[image]

The one problem here is that there's no reference to what those colors are supposed to be (as in... a legend).  If you want to add that, you would put `color=` within `aes(...)` so that a legend key is created, and assign the ***name of the key item*** within (e.g. `aes(color="name of item 1")`).  Then you would need a `scale_color_manual(...)` call to set the colors specifically... or you can do without the `scale_color_manual` object and just leave it up to `ggplot` to figure out the color scheme.

**Assigning the colors manually in legend:**

```
p + 
  geom_point(data=dat1[which(dat1$idx %in% poi1),], aes(color='poi1'), size=3) +
  geom_point(data=dat1[which(dat1$idx %in% poi2),], aes(color='poi2'), size=3) +
  geom_point(data=dat1[which(dat1$idx %in% poi3),], aes(color='poi3'), size=3) +
  scale_color_manual(values=list('poi1'='red','poi2'='blue','poi3'='green'))
```

[image]

**Without manual color assignment.**  `ggplot` just uses the theme's default color palette.

```
p + 
  geom_point(data=dat1[which(dat1$idx %in% poi1),], aes(color='poi1'), size=3) +
  geom_point(data=dat1[which(dat1$idx %in% poi2),], aes(color='poi2'), size=3) +
  geom_point(data=dat1[which(dat1$idx %in% poi3),], aes(color='poi3'), size=3)
```

[image]

#### Adding a vertical line and showing that in the legend

Related to the follow up question in the comment to this solution: **How would you add a vertical line for xintercept=poi3 and have that shown in the legend?**

You could just add individual calls to `geom_vline` with separate values for `xintercept=`, but if you have many this is just kind of bad practice.  A better practice is to have one `geom_vline` call where you set the `data=` as `poi3`.  `ggplot` wants to receive a dataframe as `data=`, so in the code below you'll see I force this conversion via `as.data.frame(...`.  Forcing a data frame makes a datframe of 2 observations with one column called "poi3", so that's what we will assign as the `xintercept=` aesthetic.  This works... but you'll see it's not quite right:

```
p +
  geom_point(data=dat1[which(dat1$idx %in% poi1),], aes(color='poi1'), size=3) +
  geom_point(data=dat1[which(dat1$idx %in% poi2),], aes(color='poi2'), size=3) +
  geom_vline(data=as.data.frame(poi3), aes(xintercept=poi3, color='poi3'),
    linetype=2, size=1) +
  scale_color_manual(values=list('poi1'='red','poi2'='blue','poi3'='green2'))
```

[image]

The green line is added to the legend, but it's added "behind" all the points as a line + point.  What we want is a separate legend.  `ggplot2` tries to combine legends where possible.  What we'll do is kind of a cheat, which is to force `ggplot2` to create another legend for `linetype`, and just set `color='green2'` outside of `aes()` in the `geom_vline` call.  This removes the color of the line from the legend created for "colour" and adds another legend for "linetype" showing only our line.  The final fix is to set the value for `linetype` via `scale_manual_linetype`.  Since there's only one key here, you only need one value.

```
p +
geom_point(data=dat1[which(dat1$idx %in% poi1),], aes(color='poi1'), size=3) +
geom_point(data=dat1[which(dat1$idx %in% poi2),], aes(color='poi2'), size=3) +
geom_vline(
    data=as.data.frame(poi3), aes(xintercept=poi3, linetype='poi3'),
    color='green2', size=1) +
scale_color_manual(values=list('poi1'='red','poi2'='blue')) +
scale_linetype_manual(values=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, and @Ryan, you can use `geom_pointrange` if you want a point with a vertical line going through it - just hard to make out in this particular plot if you do that.

Comment: thanks this is great explanation. If I want to leave `poi3` as a vertical line (created by `geom_vline()`) how would I add that to the legend as well (this one would be  a green line in the legend, instead of a dot)

Comment: I made that comment before your comment updated, thanks!

Comment: Hi @Ryan - I've added additional information in the question that addresses how to have `geom_vline()` added (in addition to the `geom_point` calls).  Hope it works for you: if you have additional questions on formatting and etc, I would open another question and you can link back to here and let me know.  I'll be happy to supply an answer there too.